# PHP PDO Notification system

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently making a notification system for my admin panel. Right now i got 2 questions:

DB table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(265) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(265) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(265) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seen` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

1. What is the best way to set the notification to seen (can't provide any code at the moment, so just tell me the easiest way to do this.)?
2. I'm going to send the same notifications to all staff on the admin panel. So should i just make multiple records in the database with each user id, or are there any better way doing this?

Comment: Does the seen attribute need to be individual for staff?  Do you need to track when it was seen? Do you want the notification to be editable?

Comment: @KevinPei, It just have to be set to seen=1 for the individual, so it get removed from the notifications for him/her.

Comment: As to point 2: Always try to avoid duplication of data in your DB. It seems like you need two tables; one of the notifications and one for the link between these and the users.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, what is the problem with duplication?

Comment: What does a "notification" represent in your system?  Is it a message to an individual user, or is the notification a message that is broadcast to multiple users?

Comment: @MikeBrant, is it both. New orders needs to go to all staffs and then things like new posts need to go to the individual user.

Comment: @JensJørgen Well it sounds like you have two different types of messages which may need to be handled in different ways and possibly with different tables.

Comment: @Jens: The most obvious problem is that the same data is present twice, or more. It makes your database bigger than it needs to be. In the worst case it makes it more difficult to access your data: For instance, searching in notifications of all users will take much longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're asking for the "better way", answers may vary. This is my take on it though:

1. Have a master table listing notifications
2. Have a table dedicated to notification distribution

[image]

This is known as a one-to-many relationship.

Advantages?

1. You can edit the notification information without messing with a table full of duplicate notifications.
2. Follows the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle

**How do you make it seen** 
There are two possible ways IMO:

1. Have the notification redirect the user to a page that first sets it to "seen", then have that page redirect them to the actual notification link
2. When the user clicks the notification, use `preventDefault()` in javascript to stop the navigation, send an ajax get request to a php page that sets it to "seen", then use `location.href` to redirect the user to their destination

Comment: @JensJørgen set viewed in the `notification_views` table to true/1.

Comment: Yea, but how to do this when i click on the notification. How do i get it to the perform the update?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have column "seen" in your table. Default is 0 (not seen), set it to 1 and that means notification is seen.
2. Make multiple entries in table notification. Entries have different uid (user id), and that way you can get notifications for wanted user.

Comment: I know it have to be set to 1, but how to do this the best way? Because when i click on the notification, it will direct me the the link.